# Quantum lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus, quantum-computing, reference-request, computation-models

Classically, there are 3 popular ways to think about computation: Turing machine, circuits, and lambda-calculus (I use this as a catch all for most functional views). All 3 have been fruitful ways to think about different types of problems, and different fields use different formulation for this reason.

When I work with quantum computing, however, I only ever think about the circuit model. Originally, QC was defined in terms of [quantum Turing machines](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/125/55) but as far as I understand, this definition (although equivalent to quantum circuits if both are formulated carefully) has not been nearly as fruitful. The 3rd formulation (in terms of lambda-calculus or similar functional settings) I am completely unfamiliar with. Hence my questions:

- **What are useful definitions of quantum lambda-calculus (or other functional paradigms)?**
- **What subfields of QIP gain deeper insight from using this formulation instead of the circuit model?**

---

#### Notes

I am aware that I am ignoring many other popular formalisms like cellular automata, RAM-models, etc. I exclude these mostly because I don't have experience with thinking in terms of these models classically, let alone [quantumly](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/6932/1037).

I am also aware that there are popular alternatives in the quantum setting, such as measurement-based, topological, and adiabatic. I do not discuss them because I am not familiar with the classical counterparts.

Comment: I think this would be fine on [cstheory.se] also. :)

Comment: @Kaveh I am highly confused as to where to ask between cstheory and CS.SE :(. I decided not to ask on cstheory because I had come across a [recent thesis](http://yannick.delbecque.org/publications/thesis/Delbecque2008-QuantumGamesQuantumTypes.pdf) that talks about quantum functional programming (in section 2.2) but haven't had the time to carefully think about it. So I thought: hey, I'll ask a half-baked question.

Comment: Hopefully it will lead to a baked question for cstheory. :)

Comment: You might want to take a look at [LPQL](https://bitbucket.org/BrettGilesUofC/lqpl), a linear functional quantum programming language developed at Calgary.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

here is a half-baked answer:
I know that Ugo Dal Lago at University of Bologna has been studying quantum lambda calculus. You may want to check [his publications](http://www.cs.unibo.it/~dallago/research.html) and perhaps this one in particular:

[Quantum implicit computational complexity](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2009.07.045) by U. Dal Lago, A. Masini, M. Zorzi.

I am saying it's a half-baked answer, because I haven't had chance to read any of his works.

Answer (score 13):

Apologies in advance for the shameless plug, but there is a paper of mine on a quantum lambda calculus that you may find interesting. It is called *The Dagger Lambda Calculus* and provides a higher-order representation for the diagrammatic circuits that the categorical school of quantum computation have introduced:

http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.1633

You can also check my talk on YouTube for more info:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pDPVd1BukI

Other works in the area include the Selinger-Valiron quantum lambda calculi, and the lambda calculus by Andre van Tonder: [[Sel04a](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.94.463)], [[Sel04b](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.144.6380)], [[vTD03](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0312174)], [[vT04](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0307150)], [[SV04](http://arxiv.org/abs/cs.LO/0404056)], [[SV08](http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.0813)], [[SV10](http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/papers.html#qlambdabook)].