# Quantum Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines, quantum-computing

Is there a formal definition of a 'Quantum Turing machine'? I am mainly interested in how the tape position would move.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, you were almost there : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Turing_machine

Comment: They add :'The above is merely a sketch of a quantum Turing machine, rather than its formal definition, as it leaves vague several important details'.

Comment: Indeed, but you can look at the papers in the sources of the article for more complete answers. See also https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-to-define-quantum-turing-machines?rq=1

Comment: Personally, I think that 'quantum' refers to tending the discrete time intervals between state transitions to zero, hence creating a continuous process. This, for example solves the non-Turing problem of colliding spheres.